# Another way to measure closed set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset [0,1]$ be a closed set. For each $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we define $b(N)$ be the number integers $0 \leq n \leq N-1$ such that $$\left[ \dfrac{n}{N},\dfrac{n+1}{N} \right] \cap A \neq \emptyset$$.
Prove $\lim \limits_{N \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{b(N)}{N}=m(A)$ where $m(A)$ is the Lebesgue measure of $A$.

What I'm thinking is the collection of sets $\left[ \dfrac{n}{N},\dfrac{n+1}{N} \right]$ will cover $A$ and we are measuring the volume by $\dfrac{b(N)}{N}$. But I don't know how to continue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the covers, we get $b(N)\cdot\frac1N\ge m(A)$.

**Hint:** For the other direction, let $B=(0,1)\setminus A$, this is open so can be written as a countable disjoint union of open intervals $(x_i,y_i)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more the relation of open intervals and $\left[ \dfrac{n}{N},\dfrac{n+1}{N} \right]$?

Comment: Each $x_i$ and $y_i$ can be approximated by *rational* numbers, specifically consider $\frac{\lceil Nx_i\rceil}N\to x_i$ and $\frac{\lfloor Ny_,i\rfloor}N\to y_i$.

Comment: Thank you, now I got it